# Include file into lib folder of nuget package

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

Upon running `dotnet pack` on the solution. I am able to create a Nuget package and see the `dll` and XML file inside the lib folder of the Nuget package.

However when building the `.sln`, there is an another file `(eg. abc.deps.json)` which is generated. This file however by default is not included in the NuGet package.

How can I also include this `deps.json` file in the NuGet package?

Note I don't wish to create a manual .nuspec for it. Since the process has to be later automated in CI/CD